# Why would I not use SqlBulkCopy.EnableStreaming?

Tags: c#, sql-server

The documentation says that it uses less memory, and my ad hoc performance tests show that it is faster. So why would I ever choose to not enable streaming?

Reference: [SqlBulkCopy.EnableStreaming Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am just assuming, maybe it's recommended not to use it on production servers as it will probably consume large amounts of memory? Otherwise, I don't see why not using it.

Comment: I guess the difference lies with the amount of data that is being processed. For. e.g. If you are processing a single record, `EnableStreaming` property can be set to false in order to avoid the unnecessary overhead created by the `IDataReader` instance that will be created while processing records in a stream.

Comment: Was just wondering the same. If I had to make a guess, it might actually be slower to use streaming but save on memory. If it weren't, then there would really be no point in having this feature. The idea that they might add a feature like this to make processing a single record faster as @PrashantTiwari suggested seems a little strange to me.

Comment: @BVernon that’s a bad analogy here; there are no extenuating circumstances that let you circumvent SO topic rules. If you feel this question can be edited to be on topic, **then edit the question**. You have the editing privilege, use it! Closure is not a permanent state, if improved the community can always reopen questions again.

Comment: @martin pieters it's an extreme analogy; not a bad one. The idea of enforcing the letter over the spirit of the law is the point. But even so, this doesn't violate SO rules. It is actually very focused and it's quite silly to suggest this question is too broad to have an objective answer.